# Is it possible to send two different body for to recipients and copy recipients in sp_send_dbmail

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

*My requirement is to send mail with to and cc options with enable and disable of button along with same content..*

***CASE 1 : T0 recipients button to be shown.
 CASE 2 : Copy recipients button to be hided.***

I am using **sp_send_dbmail** procedure to send mail. Is there any possibility,  Can anyone help with this?

```
 EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
 @profile_name = 'VoiceSQLMail',
 @recipients = 'test@co.uk',
 @copy recepients = 'test1@co.uk',
 @body1 = 'Al It Works! No Sales Were Made Today',
 @body2 = 'Al ',
 @subject = 'test';
        if(@recipients)
          @body1
        else
          @body2
```

Comment: You could send two emails. The whole point of *Carbon Copy* is that it's identical to the original.

Comment: I don’t understand your question but.... you certainly can’t make user interface (hiding buttons?) changes

Comment: @Nick . I have to send mail for approval with yes button. To and cc options both to be present. The recipients in to mail id will do approval. So button to be shown for to mail id and to be disabled for cc mail ids.

Comment: Now I understand. No it's not possible to do that. I suggest you describe what you are actually trying to do. Trying to use email for these kind of purposes is not a good idea. What kind of button was it going to be? A HTML button in the email or a MS outlook voting button?

Comment: By the way, this question has nothing to do with SQL. SQL reflects the capabilities of e-mail functionality which, as stated by others, do not support what you are asking for (and hence SQL neither).

Comment: @Nick Its an HTML button. For each new resource to recruit, request to be raised. Will be sending mails for each request. The raised request to be accepted by high authority through mail. Should send mail (To : high authority) and  CC(to person who raised request). For approval button to be shown to high authority. For the recipients in CC it should be hidden.

Comment: and when the button is pressed, what system recognises it and stores the result? _that_ is where you need to put this logic - in the external app. _quite simply this cannot be done inside an email_